# Meteor: Run multiple websites on a single instance

Tags: meteor, scaling

I have several meteor apps which I currently run in individual meteor instances. This requires that I have several meteor processes running at the same time, each occupying it's own port. I therefore need to configure the server whenever I add a new project (using reverseproxy to redirect incoming request on port 80 to the corresponding meteor ports).

I could only find information about running multiple meteor instances for scaling, but nothing about having multiple apps in one instance.

Comment: What's your question? What's your setup (host, OS, proxy, ...)?

Comment: @GabrielGM My questin is basically: Can I run more than one website in a single meteor (node.js) container.. (i.e the process that is started with "meteor run"). My host is AWS EC2, OS: Windows or ubuntu, Proxy: Nginx

Comment: "meteor run" can only run one application. If you want multiple meteor apps on one server, you need to run each one on their port and reverse proxy them.